# To render each of the element of a string in a new line using Angular4 renderer

Tags: angular

```
create() {
 this.tooltip = this.renderer.createElement('div');
 this.renderer.appendChild( 
 this.tooltip,this.renderer.createText(this.tooltipTitle);
);

this.renderer.appendChild(document.body, this.tooltip);
```

Eg: In my application

this.tooltipTitle = "Apple,Ball,Cat,Dog,Elephant"

Expected Result

```
Apple 
Ball
Cat
Dog
```

Comment: how about tansforming it to an array with `this.tooltipTitle.split(",")` before ?

Comment: Yeah anything would help, and it should look like                                    
Apple                                                                                                                         then new line Ball                                                                                                                     then new line Cat

Comment: @Enthu does this need to use the Angular renderer directly? I believe the `ngFor` directive will use this under the hood anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
import { Component, Renderer2 } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {

  tooltipTitle = "Apple,Ball,Cat,Dog,Elephant";
  tooltip: HTMLElement;

  constructor(private renderer: Renderer2) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.create();
  }

  create() {
    // creating the array
    let titles = this.tooltipTitle.split(",")
    // append each val of the resulting array to the tooltip
    titles.forEach(title => {
      const p = this.renderer.createElement('p');
      this.renderer.appendChild(
        p,
        this.renderer.createText(title),
      );
      this.renderer.appendChild(document.body, p);
    });

  }
}
```

---

### UPDATE:

You can also create a `<br>` tag after the text and align it more to your current code. Something like this:

```
import { Component, Renderer2 } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {

  tooltipTitle = "Apple,Ball,Cat,Dog,Elephant";
  tooltip: HTMLElement;

  constructor(private renderer: Renderer2) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.create();
  }

  create() {
    this.tooltip = this.renderer.createElement('div');
    this.tooltipTitle.split(',').forEach((text) => {
      this.renderer.appendChild(this.tooltip, this.renderer.createText(text));
      this.renderer.appendChild(this.tooltip, this.renderer.createElement('br'));
      this.renderer.appendChild(document.body, this.tooltip);
    });

  }
}
```

---

> Here's an Updated [**Working Sample StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kruybx) for your ref.

Comment: here we are missing tooltip html element

Comment: @Enthu, I actually did that with the `const p`. Is the `tooltip` really required?

Comment: While debugging, I see the code is working but not getting appended to the view I guess , please take a look in the example I have given , I am unable to match up yours , a little tweak might help, thanks

Comment: thanks a ton the updated sol is working perfectly, previous sol of yours was working(as in the values were getting appended to the dom but on browser only the last value was visible).  One last query I have , how can I add a class to the createElement('div') , so that I can give font styling and all.

Comment: I had posted another question related to Unit testing using Karma, I needed to resolve the service dependency error, If you could help me out with that query it would be really great, thanks

Comment: could you please help with adding of a class to the createElement('div') , so that I can apply font styling , I tried giving .addClass but it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

**!!!** *note that my answer may need correction: I didn't use Angular for so long I forgot most of it* **!!!**

but my answer will give you an hint on how to do:

I think making an array of your title may help

```js
create() {
  this.tooltip = this.renderer.createElement('div');

  // creating the array
  let titles = this.tooltipTitle.split(",")

  // append each val of the resulting array to the tooltip
  titles.forEach(title => {
    this.renderer.appendChild( 
      this.tooltip,
      this.renderer.createText(title);
    );
  });

  this.renderer.appendChild(document.body, this.tooltip);
}
```